# Causal assumptions behind SVAR with sign-restrictions identification

Tags: time-series, causality, assumptions, vector-autoregression

Which causal assumptions are (explicitly or implicitly) made in identification of a structural vector autoregression (SVAR) model with sign-restrictions (see e.g. Uhlig 2005)? By *“causal assumption”* is understood *“any constraint on a causal model that cannot be realized by imposing statistical assumptions”* (Pearl 2009, p.39). Examples of causal assumptions in time series context can be found in [this notebook](https://github.com/jakobrunge/tigramite/blob/master/tutorials/tigramite_tutorial_assumptions.ipynb) or Runge (2018).

In particular, my impression is that assumption of **causal sufficiency** (i.e., measured variables include all of the common causes) would not be met as identification via sign restrictions essentially “invents” shock series that have no direct correspondence to the variables in the model. However, Demiralp et al (2007, p.10) note that *“the SVAR literature implicitly endorses causal sufficiency when it imposes diagonal covariance matrices as part of the identification strategy”*; I am not fully convinced that this applies to sign-restriction identification but rather just to typical Wold causal ordering case (i.e., contemporary exclusion restrictions).

References:

- [Demiralp et al (2007)](https://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/abs/10.1111/j.1468-0084.2007.00496.x): A bootstrap method for identifying and evaluating a structural vector autoregression
- [Pearl (2009)](http://bayes.cs.ucla.edu/BOOK-2K/): Causality
- [Runge (2018)](https://aip.scitation.org/doi/10.1063/1.5025050): Causal network reconstruction from time series: From theoretical assumptions to practical estimation
- [Uhlig (2005)](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/abs/pii/S0304393205000073): What are the effects of monetary policy on output? Results from an agnostic identification procedure